# Change a scroll bar style

Tags: javascript, html, css

Please refer this link for the example: [CLICK HERE](https://css-tricks.com/examples/WebKitScrollbars/)

I am using a below css for change the scroll bar:

```
/* For the "inset" look only */
html {
    overflow: auto;
}
body {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    left: 20px;
    bottom: 20px;
    right: 20px;
    padding: 30px; 
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: scroll;
}

/* Let's get this party started */
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 6px;
}

/* Track */
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3); 
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
    border-radius: 6px;
}

/* Handle */
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    background: rgba(255,0,0,0.8); 
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.5); 
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:window-inactive {
    background: rgba(255,0,0,0.4); 
}
```

This css only change the width of the y scroll , how can i change a width of the x scroll.

Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Do you know that's a propietary style only valid for chrome ? Do you know the resultant scrollbars will be ugly and visually bad for the eyes? I recommend a js scrollbar if you really need to stylize it: Perfect Scrollbar ( https://noraesae.github.io/perfect-scrollbar/ ) You can stylize it with all css you want

Comment: `::-webkit-scrollbar {height: 12px;}` will work, but I agree with @MarcosPérezGude, you should go for js scrollbar

Comment: @AbhishekPandey , thanks it's work for me when i add a `height:6px;`

Comment: Use height:6px  `::-webkit-scrollbar {width: 6px; height: 6px;}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**DEMO:**

http://plnkr.co/edit/bBEj9xa6TucnJq6scIsq?p=preview

Use `::-webkit-scrollbar {width: 6px; height: 6px;}`

Check demo.

http://plnkr.co/edit/bBEj9xa6TucnJq6scIsq?p=preview

Also note that CSS based scrollbars are not suitable for all browsers. So, my recommendation would be to go for js based scrollbars.

I prefer jquery.nicescroll

https://github.com/inuyaksa/jquery.nicescroll

Answer (score 1):

You have specify height to increase width of the x scroll.
**for example {}**

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can style the scrollbar both in x and y direction. heres the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a7kf6sqy/)

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 12px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  border-radius: 10px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for your answer but the Solution is:

```
/* Let's get this party started */
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 6px;height:6px;
}
```